# Les exemples effectifs et l'axiome du choix

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

In his paper "Les exemples effectifs et l'axiome du choix" Sierpiński writes

"...6) On peut définir effectivement un nombre, même un entier qui n'est pas *calculable* au sens de M. Borel. ..."

> My question: What is "computable in the sense of M. Borel" and who is
>   M. Borel?

I'm puzzled to the extent that I'm tempted to believe that the M should have been an E and is a scanning mistake. Or perhaps I am mistranslating the "calculable". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps "Monsieur Borel"?

Comment: on page is the quote?

Comment: Here is a link to the paper: http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv2i1p14bwm

Comment: the foot-notes on page 113, Sierpinski also refers to M. Zermelo, this would support Asaf's conjecture that the M. stands for monsieur.

Comment: I can't find the article of Borel (M or E) that is referred to. If you can, I can try to understand from it what it means by calculable.

Comment: @Ittay: Actually both Borel and Zermelo were E. so it might be just the same uniform replacement. It doesn't necessarily support my hypothesis! [Don't be an engineer, be a mathematician](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/3.htm#black)! :-)

Comment: The paper also references [M. Zalcwasser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygmunt_Zalcwasser), [M. Hamel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Hamel), [M. Lebesgue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Lebesgue), etc.

Comment: @Arthur: That's a more established theory now. I didn't know that Mark Hamill was a mathematician. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: He must have learnt the ways of the (Cohen) force.

Comment: Monsieur! Obviously. I didn't see the other "M's".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The M. Borel mentioned is without any doubt Émile Borel. And the term "computable in the sense of M. Borel" probably applies to the definition of the number, not to the number itself. I think it just means that we have no effective means of determining the number specified by the definition. In fact the paper mentioned the definition "The smallest natural number $k$ such that every natural number can be written as the sum of at most $k$ fourth powers of natural numbers", of which it was known at the time only that $19\leq k\leq37$. Indeed the definition gives no effective means to compute this $k$, although of course every one of the numbers $19,20,21,\ldots,36,37$ (or indeed any given natural number) can itself be trivially "computed".

Comment: Thank you very much. A minor remark: I think the "bicarré(s)" which you translated as "fourth power" really means "quartic with only even powers of the unknown" (direct translation (of mine) of the entry about bicarré in [Wictionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bicarr%C3%A9)).

Comment: @MattN. Curious, I've never seen it used that way. But you must be right, my dictionary says essentially the same thing. But Sierpiński writes "bicarrés de nombres naturels", and that makes no sense if they designate some kind of quartic. Which coefficients? If you can choose them freely (as natural numbers), you can make any natural number into a single "bicarré" (evaluated at $1$).

Comment: And according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem#The_number_g.28k.29) the number defined here was shown to be equal to $19$ by R. Balasubramanian, in 1986.